# How to remove a subView

Tags: objective-c

I added a subview using

```
myViewController *myVC = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil];
[self addSubview:myVC.view];
[myVC release];
```

how can I remove it again from a myViewController method ?

I tried

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[myVC.view removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: I tried to do this by adding a back button with an IBAction to my Subview calling from the subViewController:
[self.view removefromsuperview], but that doesn't work.

Comment: I got a step further on this. I add the subview from a UIScrollView. Clicking the back-button on the added view seems to interfere with the touch events ... for a separate discussion